# Meaning of a function top(Infinity)

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am a newbie at d3js and came across to the following piece of code in d3js:

data = distance.top(Infinity);

where 'distance' is a column read from a csv file.

What does this piece of code exactly do?

Comment: Could you give a link to the code that uses this? Or some minimal working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a Crossfilter dimension, so check the API reference for [dimension.top](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_top).

> If there are fewer than k records selected according to all of the crossfilter's filters, then an array smaller than k will be returned. For example, to retrieve all selected payments in descending order by total:
>
> `var allPayments = paymentsByTotal.top(Infinity);`